# IF ELSE in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement

I have the following column in Microsoft SQL Server called `Type` and I want to create another column called `Type 1` which would be 1 if account starts with letter A, 2 if account starts with D....

I am new with this so could someone please advise?

```
Type    Type 1  
AD  1  
AV  1  
AC  1  
DE  2  
DR  2  
DG  2  
KL  3  
KL  3
```

Comment: Advise on what? Good/bad idea? How to implement?

Comment: What is the rule for 1 = A , 2 = D?? I thought 2 should be = B

Comment: Look at `CASE` instead of `IF`. - e.g. `CASE WHEN Type LIKE 'A%' then 1 WHEN Type Like 'D%' THEN 2 WHEN ...`

Comment: Please advise on how to implement this by SQL. Right now, I only have column type 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CASE` instead of `IF`:

```
SELECT 
    Type,
    CASE 
        WHEN Type LIKE 'A%' then 1 
        WHEN Type Like 'D%' THEN 2 
        WHEN ...
    END AS Type1
...
```

Comment: One more questions: I want to put this new column Type 1 into Where clause and it's in error. Could you please help?

Comment: You can't reference a computed column in a `WHERE` clause because the `WHERE` is evaluated first.  You can either use a subquery or change the `WHERE` to use table fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Type,
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Type, 1, 1)='A' THEN 1
     WHEN SUBSTRING(Type, 1, 1)='D' THEN 2
     WHEN SUBSTRING(Type, 1, 1)='K' THEN 3
     ELSE 0  END as 'Type 1'
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, a CASE statement will meet this need easily.

If you are going to be doing this translation often, consider adding a computed column to the table like so:

```
if object_id('ComputedColumnTest') is not null
  drop table ComputedColumnTest;
go

create table ComputedColumnTest
(
  TYPE varchar(2)
);
alter table ComputedColumnTest     --<<<<<<<
add TYPE1 AS                       --<<<<<<<
  (                                --<<<<<<<
  case when [TYPE] like 'A%' then 1--<<<<<<<
       when [TYPE] like 'D%' then 2--<<<<<<<
       else 0                      --<<<<<<<
  end                              --<<<<<<<
  )                                --<<<<<<<

insert into ComputedColumnTest([type]) values ('AD')
insert into ComputedColumnTest([type]) values ('AV')
insert into ComputedColumnTest([type]) values ('AC')
insert into ComputedColumnTest([type]) values ('DE')
insert into ComputedColumnTest([type]) values ('DR')
insert into ComputedColumnTest([type]) values ('DG')
insert into ComputedColumnTest([type]) values ('KL')
insert into ComputedColumnTest([type]) values ('KL')

select *
from ComputedColumnTest
where type1 = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to number using the first letter of the 'type' column in ascending order, use the **DENSE_RANK()** in SQL Server.

```
  ;WITH cte_1
   AS
    ( SELECT Type
                    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY LEFT(Type,1) ) [Type 1]
      FROM YourTable)
    SELECT *
     FROM cte_1
      WHERE [Type 1]=1 --here you can add your filter criteria
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put `WHERE` on computed column, you have to wrap it in subquery.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Type
        , (CASE LEFT(Type, 1)
            WHEN 'A' THEN 1
            WHEN 'D' THEN 2
        END) AS Type1
) a
WHERE Type1 = 'some condition'
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been answered already but I thought I would add my 2 cents.

If the amount of possible values is going to get very large, causing the case statement to become very large you may want to consider creating a loopkup table for yourself.

You would the be able to just do a join between the 2 tables to get the relevant column value.